# python setup.py import subpackage directly

Tags: python, setup.py

Consider the following minimal `setup.py` example.

```
alpha
├── beta
│   ├── beta.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── gamma
│   ├── theta
│   │   ├── theta.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

with setup.py defined as

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='alpha',
    author='author',
    packages=[
        'beta',
        'gamma.theta',
    ],
)
```

I then install with `pip install -e .` and everything works as expected i.e. I can do `import beta`, `import gamma` and `from gamma import theta`.

My question: is it possible to modify `setup.py` so that I could import `theta` directly i.e. `import theta` instead of having to use `from gamma import theta`?

Comment: how about `import gamma.theta` ?

Comment: @reportgunner That would work and does not seem too bad because it is a minimal example, but in the case of having more levels I would like to be able to avoid doing something like `import gamma.theta.pkg1.pkg2`, if it possible of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can put modules on the level of `gamma` that will only contain

```
from gamma.theta.pkg1.pkg2 import *
```

and call it `pkg2`. Then you can do

```
import pkg2
```

I suppose that this will be really confusing to the user and I haven't tested this so I'm not sure how it will work with a lot of imports for the child packages.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the [package_dir](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages) parameter and specify location of your package shall rich you to the point you want to get to:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='alpha',
    author='author',
    packages=[
        'theta',
    ],
    package_dir={'theta': 'gamma/'}
)
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: path gamma/ cannot end with '/'`. If I remove the `/` the installation works successfully but then I can't `import theta`, I have to use `from gamma import theta` or `import gamma.theta`, which is not what I am looking for. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: yes, maybe, I guess you can try to manage installation of `theta` only and than proceed further, I have managed to have working installation locally.  You can install with -I flag to pip which tells it `ignore installed` as the following: pip install -I -e .